# Link with time tag

Tags: html

What would be the correct?

```
<a>
  <time>TIME_HERE</time>
</a>
```

**or**

```
<time>
  <a>TIME_HERE</a>
</time>
```

Or maybe none of the above are valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The specification indicates that without a `datetime` attribute the content should be a valid date or time string, thus the `anchor` should wrap the `time` element rather than the reverse.  If a `datetime` attribute is present, the contents need not specify a date or time and you could conceivably have an `anchor` tag inside.  Note that none of the examples in the specification have descendent elements (other than text nodes) inside a time element.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element